# Reason for backtick in config file?

Tags: migration, entity-framework-5, config

[Microsoft's instructions on EF configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) show this example.

```
<databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly], [Blogging.Migrations.Configuration, MyAssembly]], EntityFramework" />
```

What is the meaning of the `` `2 `` in the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion has two type params.

From [**msdn**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621):

> When we create an instance of this initializer we need to specify the
>   context type (BlogContext) and the migrations configuration
>   (Configuration) - the migrations configuration is the class that got
>   added to our Migrations folder when we enabled Migrations.

So, that's why there's the `` `2 `` in the configuration file.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can find out more about this syntax?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if there's a reliable source with it all compiled together. If you find one via Google, I'd be interested to see it myself.  Trudging through msdn for particular tidbits seems to be standard.